# How can I mark a card in Trello as done and keep it in the original list?

Tags: trello

Is there a way to mark a card as done without moving it to a list named "done"? I'd like to keep the card in the list but show that it is done.

We love using Trello.  I am using it with a bunch of pastors to develop and project manage the work for weekly messages.

Comment: I have a new list called "Done - Requires Checking" and move anything to that list, until it's actually formally checked by whoever needs to approve the job as completed.

Answer (score 15):

Trello doesn't have a predefined way to mark a card as done, but you could certainly name a label "Done" and apply it to cards that you have completed.

Comment: It still makes the date display in red after the due date.

Answer (score 10):

Trello has recently added this feature to mark a card done by clicking on due date and it does turn green.

http://blog.trello.com/mark-a-trello-card-as-done

No more moving cards into done list or labeling it done.

> If you add a due date to a card, once the task is completed you can now check it off on the card, changing it from a stress-inducing red to a soothing green color. Ahh, the satisfaction.

[image]

Comment: Add essential contents of the link into answer, that would be more useful.

Comment: What exactly is a bitecoin?

Comment: @JohnDorian bitcoin is probably meant

Comment: is possible without adding a due date?

Comment: Oct 2020 and you still must have a due date to do this.. How can basic functionality like this still not be there!??

Answer (score 7):

If a card has a due date, placing in a different list or changing the label won't disable alerts as the date approaches and passes.  Removing the date is a workaround, but one that obviously prevents future analysis on actual vs. target dates.

An ideal solution would provide the desired status and disable due date notifications.

Answer (score 3):

You could colour code that card with all of the colours to signify its completion.

Answer (score 3):

Add a checklist (as little as a single item: "done"), then mark the card as done in the checklist. The card will visually display in green a checkmark for the checklist.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't but i would like that too. I normally have 3 main lists - To do, Doing & Done. I then move the cards around as needed.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a Chrome Extension for this called [Trello Tasks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trello-tasks/icedfgfhjcnidibolnnfbjnjbkbfgcic?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)
that can be toggled on/off by board.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stickers. The default stickers includes a checkmark which I use to mark things as done. It may be a little bit big, but it stays in the list and doesn't move around your card.

Answer (score 1):

I too like to have due dates acknowledged and see in my lists which tasks have been completed and which are still left to do.

I quickly worked out that this was not going to be possible in Trello.  So I have created a Completed Tasks list, and when I transfer a completed task to this list I change the due date to the date I completed the task.  Not ideal, but it does help me with tracking how many tasks I get through each day. Because I also use the labels, I can see how many tasks in each group I get through each day.

Maybe in future editions of Trello this element might be improved.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the Power-Up called Butler to automate my interaction with Trello. I have one that when I flag a card with a green label, it sets the card as done and move it to the archive folder. 
You can create an intermediate step to move the card to a temporary folder, for instance when you apply a given tag. After that, when finished, use another automation like mine.

This Power-Up is very easy to use and extremely convenient.

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] I could do it. You can go to the Butler automations screen and **add a new Rule**
You will get rule suggestions like this:
when a card is added to list "Done" by anyone
mark the due date as complete

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Instead of, or in addition to, the color label, you could change the card title from "abc xyz" to "Done - abc xyz"  or any other keyword of your choice.